# How to create an AI model and use in Boxever Decision or Sitecore CDP decisioning

Tags: cdp

In `Boxever` or `Sitecore CDP` decision Model canvas there is an option to create Analytical Model. How to create an AI model and use it in creating decision in `Boxever` or `Sitecore CDP`?

[image]

Could not find any example, any suggestions or help will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to have any AI service *(3rd party or your own)* that provides Web API endpoints for communication.

Then you need to create new AI connection in CDP and configure it:
[image]

[image]

After that, you will be able to add your created connection in Decision model and use it *(you will see it in dropdown list when you add **"Analytical Model"** to canvas)*:
[image]

If you need full example with implementation, you can see my blog post here:
https://www.brimit.com/blog/cdp-4-how-to-use-ai-connections

or watch my user group presentation here: https://youtu.be/iGLMDlItv58